# Char * that points to an array of chars = "ls\0" does not equal the string equivalent "ls\0"

Tags: c

I'm writing a shell program, and when passing values into `execv()` I need a char pointer to the name of the program (which is `ls`), and I need a pointer to an array of arrays of char pointers for the arguments.

I go through and parse the user's input, and if I type in `ls`, if I print my `char *`, `printf()` prints out "ls".  So I am parsing the line correctly and storing the correct information.  When I pass this to `execv()`, it says bad path name, but if I change my pointer manually to `progs[0] = "ls"`, then it works.  If I compare the two strings, `strcmp(mypointer, "ls")`, it shows that although mypointer prints out `"ls"`, it is not equivalent to `"ls"`.

Does anyone know why?

Here is my shell process code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char **progs;
char ***arguments;
char **mode;
char pathname[] = "/bin/";

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

//printf("\n %s \n", progs);
//fflush(stdout);

char buff[100];
FILE *p;

p = fdopen(0, "r");  //opens FD 0 (Stdin) as a stream

char * pathname;

while(1){

    //printf("I'm at the top");

    if(isatty(1) == 1){ //check to see if stdout is going to the terminal
    printstart();       //if so, print 
    }

    fgets(buff, 100, p); // Gets the input from the stdin and puts it in buff

    int processid = fork();  //fork into child to complete task

    if(processid == 0){

        //initialize all variables

        int numcmd = countcmd(buff);
        int pipes = countpipes(buff);
        int i;
        int j;

        //allocate memory for tokenization

        progs = malloc(numcmd * sizeof(char *));
        arguments = malloc((numcmd) * sizeof(char *));
        mode = malloc((numcmd*2) * sizeof(char *));

        for(i = 0; i < numcmd; i++){
            progs[i] = malloc(10* sizeof(char *));
            mode[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
            mode[2*numcmd-1-i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));
            arguments[i] = malloc(15 * sizeof(char *));
                for(j = 0; j < 15; j++){
                arguments[i][j] = malloc(15 * sizeof(char*));
                }
            }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        parse(buff); //parses input and places it in the static progs

        for(i = 0; i < 1; i++){

        printf("\n This is progs %s", arguments[0][0]);

        char temp[25];
        //strcpy(temp, "/bin/");
        strcpy(temp, progs[0]);
        //strcat(temp, ' \0');

        //*progs = "ls";
        char * ptr = progs[0];
        for(;*ptr != '\0';){
            printf("This is what pointer poitns to %c \n", *ptr++);
            }
        printf("This is the program: <<%s>>", progs[0]);
        fflush(stdout);
        char * argument[2];
        argument[0] = "ls";
        argument[1] = '\0';
        char * hell = "l\0";

        printf("This is the value of comparison %d\n", strcmp(progs[0], hell));

        char **temparg = arguments[0];
        //char temp[20] = progs[0];

        errno = 0;
        execvp("ls", *argument);

        char * error = strerror(errno);
        printf("This is the error %s", error);
        return;
        }

    }       
        else{
        int status;
        waitpid(processid, &status, WIFEXITED(status));

        }
}

return 0;
}
```

Here is my parse() code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myshell.h"

int parse(char * buff){

//Initialize all variables and pointers
int cmd = 0;
int argument = 0;
int mod = 0;
int j = 0;
int hitargs = 0;
int gotcommand = 0;
int multiarg = 0;

char ** argptr = arguments[cmd];
char * ptr1 = progs[cmd];
char * argptr2 = argptr[argument];
char * ptr2 = mode[mod];

while(buff[j] != '\0'){

    switch(buff[j]){

        case ';':
            cmd++;
            argument = 0;
            multiarg = 1;
            *argptr2++ = '\0';

            argptr = arguments[cmd];
            argptr2 = argptr[argument];
            ptr1 = progs[cmd];

            *ptr2 = buff[j];
            mod += 2;
            ptr2 = mode[mod];

        case ' ':
            if(gotcommand == 0){
            break;
            }
            else{
                if(hitargs == 0){
                hitargs = 1;
                *ptr1++ = '\0';
                argument++;
                argptr2 = argptr[argument];
                }
                else{
                argument++;
                argptr2 = argptr[argument];
                }
                break;
            }
        default:
            if(gotcommand == 0){
                *ptr1++ = (char) buff[j];
                *argptr2++ = buff[j];
                gotcommand = 1;
            }
            else if(gotcommand == 1 && hitargs == 0){
                *ptr1++ = (char) buff[j];
                *argptr2++ = buff[j];
            }
            else if(gotcommand == 1 && hitargs == 1){
                *argptr2++ = buff[j];
            }
    }

j++;
}

*argptr2++ = '\0';
*ptr1++ = '\0';

int cmdflag = 0;
int spaceflag = 0;
int argflag = 0;
int cmdct = 1; //account for null
int argumentct = 1; //account for null termination

return 1;
}
```

Sorry about the random printf statements.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Just as you can't describe your problem to a computer and expect a program to appear, you can't describe this problem and an explanation to appear. The solution to both is the same, use code!

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that your string is `"ls\n"`, not `"ls"`.  Fortunately, I don't have to guess, so I won't.

Comment: When you print the parsed `ls`, do you use `printf("<<%s>>\n", mypointer);`?  If not, do so.  It may be that there are leading or trailing blanks, or other control characters, lurking around confusing you.  The `<<` and `>>` are simply delimiters that are unlikely to appear in the actual text.

Comment: Okay, i've updated to include my code.

Comment: Please present the smallest self-contained example that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your main program should include `myshell.h` like your parsing code does.
- It would be helpful to have the missing functions (such as `countcmd()` and `countpipes()` — it isn't clear precisely what those do, though we can guess a bit from their names).
- You should have include `<unistd.h>` in your main program.
- You should have been getting warnings about undeclared functions (such as `fork()`), and you should be heeding and fixing those warnings.

  - If you were not getting those warnings, you need to add more warning options to your compilation.
  - If you use `gcc`, using `-Wall` is a good starting point.

With the warnings enabled, you get to see:

```
shex.c:95: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘execvp’ from incompatible pointer type
shex.c:99: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void
```

- The latter is best handled via `return EXIT_FAILURE;` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.
- The former is triggered by `execvp("ls", *argument);`.
- It might be better to use a plural word (arguments?) for something that contains many arguments.
- ...Oh, I see, there is a global variable `arguments`.
- You declare `char ***arguments;`.  *Ouch!*  I have used a triple pointer occasionally, but only very occasionally.  That's one too many levels of pointer most of the time, and especially for this exercise.
- Then there's also a local variable `char *argument[2];`.
- The correct call is, therefore, `execvp("ls", argument);`.

I would immediately expand on the waiting code to at least print the information:

```
    else
    {   
        int status;
        int corpse = waitpid(processid, &status, WIFEXITED(status));
        printf("Command exited: PID = %d; status = 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }
```

In your parsing code, the `case ';':` drops through into the `case ' ':`.  If that's intentional, document it (with a comment such as `/* DROP THROUGH */`); if not, insert the missing break.  Your `default:` case should probably have a break after it too.  It isn't quite crucial, but it is conventional and protects you from drop through if a new case needs to be handled.

The string of five variables declared at the end of `parse()` are superfluous; they're local variables that are never used (as the compiler tells you).

At the top of the `main()` you do:

```
FILE *p;
p = fdopen(0, "r");  //opens FD 0 (Stdin) as a stream
```

This is not necessary; `stdin` is already open as a stream.

You read from `p` (aka `stdin`) with `fgets()`.  On the whole, this is good (better than `gets()`), but you need to be aware that `fgets()` includes a newline which `gets()` does not, and you need to check the return status (you might not read anything).  You should also use `sizeof()`:

```
if (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) == 0)
    ...error - read failed...
```

The memory allocation is extraordinarily complex.  For a fixed size input like `char buff[100];`, you can afford to use non-dynamic allocation.  There can't be more than about 50 arguments total, since they're blank separated.

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

not looked into the entire code so  there may be other bugs but ith regard to the 'ls' issue you need to add the following to the parse code :

```
      while (buff[j] != '\0' && buff[j]  != '\n')
```

this ensures you don't add  'newline' to the command pointer at `*ptr1++ = (char) buff[j];`

Note [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) if it encounters new line would stop reading but would include it as part of the string.